# Rear diagonal sum in the matrix

Tags: python

I want a matrix amount that can be in any size for example 2x2 or 3x3 etc but reverse, my problem with for loops along with if not working well
Would appreciate help

for example:

```
         2,1,5
         3,6,1
         8,5,0
```

the result is 5 + 6 + 8 = 19

```
def is_diagonal_equal(matrix):

    for i in range(0, len(matrix)):
        for j in range(0, len(matrix)):
            if i == a and j == g/2:
                sum2 += matrix[i][j]
```

The function gets an initialized **matrix** with values and size

Comment: This code does not run; `g` is not defined; nor is `a`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use enumerate to get the backward progressing indexes of each row and sum() to add up the result:

```
def rearDiagSum(matrix):
    return sum(row[-i] for i,row in enumerate(matrix,1))

M = [ [2,1,5],
      [3,6,1],
      [8,5,0] ]

print(rearDiagSum(M)) # 19
```

*Note that this assumes a square matrix*